# Unexpected behavior from Cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, geospatial, geo, cartopy, great-circle

I'm trying to draw a 'straight' line on the surface of the Earth (a great circle), which should appear curved on an orthographic projection that isn't looking straight down on the curve. However, when I try to connect two points with a geodetic line in cartopy I get a line with a kink in it. Where is this kink coming from? And how can I get a correctly rendered great circle segment?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lats = [0, 36]
lons = [15, 76]
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=0, central_latitude=45))
ax.plot(lons, lats, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_global()
ax.gridlines()
```

[image: where is the kink coming from?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the option `transform=ccrs.Geodetic()`, the implication is that you need great-circle arc as a result of your `ax.plot()` statement.

Without proper setting of `projection._threshold` you will get the kinked line as you experienced.

Here is the modified code and the expected result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lats = [0, 36]
lons = [15, 76]

myProj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=0, central_latitude=45)
myProj._threshold = myProj._threshold/20. 

ax = plt.axes(projection = myProj)
ax.plot(lons, lats, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_global()
ax.gridlines()
```

[image: nokink]

Smaller values of the `threshold` will cause the plotted lines to have denser vertices along the lines. Additional vertices are not obtained by simple interpolation when great-circle arcs are required in this case.

Comment: whoa! is this documented anywhere?

Comment: looks relevant - https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/8, and associated pull https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/1815

Comment: @MichaelDelgado  Nice try. I couldn't find the better ones. Will add to the answer when I found one.